# How to change filenames according to a file with filenames and ID names?

Tags: bash

I've seen many examples here on how to replace filenames using strings within the filename (for example, myfile_000121.txt changed to 000121.txt). But what if I have a separate text file where I saved all my filenames in the first column and a completely new ID in the second column? The ID is not found anywhere within the original filenames.

Here is an example of my textfile:

```
AA5t-666_S241_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  Species_uno_R1.fastq.gz
AA5t-666_S241_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  Species_uno_R2.fastq.gz
AA5t-662-0788-AES_L002_R1_001.fastq.gz  Species_duo_R1.fastq.gz
AA5t-662-0788-AES_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz  Species_duo_R2.fastq.gz
```

So I want to use this textfile to replace the filenames in my directory (the same names in column 1) with the new names I created in column 2. I'm only aware of how to do something like this if the ID name appears within the filename.

Thank you!

Comment: Read each column into different variables, then just use those variables as arguments to the `mv` command.

Comment: Would it just be something like, for line in filelist.txt; do col1=(extract col1 somehow); col2=(extract col2 somehow); mv col1 col2; done. I just need to figure out how to save the columns as variables.

Comment: You don't know how to read a file line by line in a shell script?

Comment: Sometimes but I often just run into issues with using the while read command - I tend to stick to for loops.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash/1521498#1521498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read each column of the file into a variable and then use them as arguments to the `mv` command.

```
while read -r oldname newname
do
    mv "$oldname" "$newname"
done < filelist.txt
```

Comment: This sort of works but the newnames are all ending with an extra apostrophe at the end. But thank I can work with this!

Comment: My script isn't adding an apostrophe. It must be in the file, or maybe you copied incorrectly.

Comment: Is the apostrophe only at the end, or also at the beginning? `ls` will show filenames with apostrophe if they contain special characters.

Comment: Make sure `filelist.txt` doesn't have CRLF newlines. Use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: yes that fixed it! Had to run dos2unix. Thank you